# Is there a specific area on the far side of the moon, directly below the L2 Lagrange point in the Earth/Moon system?

Tags: the-moon, earth, lagrange-point

It seems like there should be, and if so I wonder how large an area it is, if it changes size over time, and if it moves or wobbles in some way. On the latst point, I imagine it would certainly wobble if the Moon didn't rotate around the axis defined by it's center and L2, but maybe there are more complicated reasons such as non-uniform mass distribution, the Earth's influence, etc.

I'm not asking for a specific solution, please don't work that hard! I am looking for insight onto the factors involved, and nuances based on these factors.

Thank you!
Nick

Comment: It wobbles. See [libration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration).

Comment: Thank you @doubleunary!

Comment: and of course "the L2 point" has no proper meaning at all for the Earth-Moon system to begin with; 1) the Moon's orbit is *inclined* with respect to Earth's orbital plane, so it's not a 2D problem, and 2) the Moon's orbit is elliptical, meaning that math relating to the *circular* restricted there body problem doesn't apply, even if they were coplanar. Both of these contribute to "it wobbles" if we were to invent an L2 point. But the notion of Lagrange points are nonetheless *helpful* when talking or thinking about realistic trajectories around the moon as a sort-of first order approximation.

Comment: Lagrange points are only mathematically defined in the first place for the [circular restricted three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Restricted_three-body_problem)

Comment: So much to learn, thank you @uhoh